# iOS - Returning async data request to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, asynchronous, uiviewcontroller

I have a service that contains several functions that prepare data to be submitted to a web service.

Essentially I gather my data in a ViewController, pass it to the Service, manipulate it and transform it, and then pass that information to a class which is responsible for all the data transfer (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)

ie.

ViewController:

```
var model = MyModel()
var service = MyService()

service.createNewDBEntryOnServer(model)
```

Service:

```
func createNewDBEntryOnServer(model: MyModel) -> MyModel {

    var jsonToPost = JSONService.modelToJSON(model)

    networkService.post("ext-url", jsonToPost, completion { data, response, error) in {

        //Data returned here from JSONService
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            //Can return this data to ViewController for processing
        })
    })
    return MyModel()
}
```

NetworkService 'post' method uses NSURLSession.sharedSession(), and executes an asynchronous request to the web service using session.dataTaskWithRequest

I am able to return the data just fine, but since there is a layer between my ViewController and my NetworkService, I am unsure how to detect the difference from the return on MyService before and after the async data request. In some cases I would need to display an UIActivityIndicator, so my ViewController would for example need to wait for the async response before performing a segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding completion callback parameter to `createNewDBEntryOnServer`? So:

```
var model = MyModel()
var service = MyService()

var queued = service.createNewDBEntryOnServer(model, completion {model} in {
  // this is called asynchro
  waiterPopup.dismiss();

  self.updateModel(model);
});

if (queued)
        waiterPopup.show();
```

---

*Note: in order to get rid of possible controllers disposal before callback is called, use weak pointer to self, like:*

```
var queued = service.createNewDBEntryOnServer(model, completion {model} in {
  // this is called asynchro
  if (!weakSelf)
     return;

  weakSelf.dismissWaiter();
  weakSelf.updateModel(model);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The service can post a notification via NSNotificationCenter which the view controller can listed to and then go and fetch the data from the service. If you use a delegate within the service to directly call the view controller then there is the possibility that the view controller doesn't actually exist at that point (depending upon your GUI design and lifetimes of controllers).

Personally I would myself maybe make the the service something which is an implementation detail of the model, and your view controllers request functionality from the model, which itself uses a service class. But that's neither right nor wrong, just my preference.

There's no reason to avoid using notification center, except for the fact that maybe it feels unfamiliar to you, but an asynchronous  activity using it on completion is a very common pattern in iOS. 
The other patterns would be to use a completion block or a delegate (i.e. a callback). But if you are calling back on a GUI object then there is a real possibility that object isn't there at the time of the callback so checks need to be put in place to deal with that situation if you use that pattern.

Comment: Is my approach a typical way of doing things in iOS? This design pattern I use heavily in .NET, but that is for synchronous connections. Is there a better to avoid using NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: I added a few more sentences as a response to your comment.